# PLCrashReporter ios6 crash

Tags: ios, ios6, plcrashreporter

My iOS6 app is crashing when compiled and run in release mode, please see crash report below:

```
Incident Identifier: 0267EA79-BAAB-4559-90FB-9ED8C268EB19
CrashReporter Key:   7b2d29f7c42065db47d89a8b3ae1056cf45f7d95
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         Instant Santa [5814]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B303BD19-177E-4DBB-A7C2-89BBF3331818/Instant Santa.app/Instant Santa
Identifier:      Instant Santa
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-11-10 22:30:34.889 -0600
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A525)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3a6eb3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3974495e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3a6eb302 +[NSException raise:format:] + 102
3   Instant Santa                   0x001196aa -[PLCrashReporter enableCrashReporterAndReturnError:] + 82
4   Instant Santa                   0x000b1064 -[BWQuincyManager init] (BWQuincyManager.m:182)
5   Instant Santa                   0x000b0c00 __38+[BWQuincyManager sharedQuincyManager]_block_invoke_0 (BWQuincyManager.m:107)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x334d35d6 _dispatch_client_callout + 18
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x334d4586 dispatch_once_f + 42
8   Instant Santa                   0x000b0bc0 +[BWQuincyManager sharedQuincyManager] (once.h:68)
9   Instant Santa                   0x0009f9a2 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:51)
10  UIKit                           0x33f5ba74 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
11  UIKit                           0x33f5b5f8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1164
12  UIKit                           0x33f53806 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694
13  UIKit                           0x33efbcea -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1006
14  UIKit                           0x33efb778 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
15  UIKit                           0x33efb1ba _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
16  GraphicsServices                0x3a78f5f2 _PurpleEventCallback + 586
17  GraphicsServices                0x3a78f222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3a6c03e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3a6c0386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3a6bf20a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3a632238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3a6320c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
23  UIKit                           0x33f52440 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
24  UIKit                           0x33f4f28c UIApplicationMain + 1116
25  Instant Santa                   0x0009f73e main (main.m:16)
26  Instant Santa                   0x0009f6f4 start + 36


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a455350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339edfb2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a2a366 abort + 90
3   Instant Santa                   0x00119912 uncaught_exception_handler + 22
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3a6eb6cc __handleUncaughtException + 624
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39744a46 _objc_terminate() + 126
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ae3118 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ae31b0 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ae459a __cxa_throw + 118
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3974499e objc_exception_throw + 90
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3a6eb302 +[NSException raise:format:] + 102
11  Instant Santa                   0x001196aa -[PLCrashReporter enableCrashReporterAndReturnError:] + 82
12  Instant Santa                   0x000b1064 -[BWQuincyManager init] (BWQuincyManager.m:182)
13  Instant Santa                   0x000b0c00 __38+[BWQuincyManager sharedQuincyManager]_block_invoke_0 (BWQuincyManager.m:107)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x334d35d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x334d4586 dispatch_once_f + 42
16  Instant Santa                   0x000b0bc0 +[BWQuincyManager sharedQuincyManager] (once.h:68)
17  Instant Santa                   0x0009f9a2 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:51)
18  UIKit                           0x33f5ba74 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
19  UIKit                           0x33f5b5f8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1164
20  UIKit                           0x33f53806 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694
21  UIKit                           0x33efbcea -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1006
22  UIKit                           0x33efb778 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
23  UIKit                           0x33efb1ba _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
24  GraphicsServices                0x3a78f5f4 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
25  GraphicsServices                0x3a78f222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
26  CoreFoundation                  0x3a6c03e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
27  CoreFoundation                  0x3a6c0386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
28  CoreFoundation                  0x3a6bf20a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
29  CoreFoundation                  0x3a632238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
30  CoreFoundation                  0x3a6320c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
31  UIKit                           0x33f52440 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
32  UIKit                           0x33f4f28c UIApplicationMain + 1116
33  Instant Santa                   0x0009f73e main (main.m:16)
34  Instant Santa                   0x0009f6f4 start + 36
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Start by posting the top few methods in the stack trace - `-[BWQuincyManager init] (BWQuincyManager.m:182)`, `+[BWQuincyManager sharedQuincyManager] (once.h:68)`

Answer (score 1):

This happens if PLCrashReporter is already initialized before QuincyKit initializes it. Are you initializing PLCrashReporter yourself or is there any other framework installed that uses PLCrashReporter?

This is the exception that is being raised and causes the crash: https://github.com/bitstadium/PLCrashReporter/blob/master/Source/PLCrashReporter.m#L296

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, you don't need CrashReporter.framework with the new HockeySDK, see here: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration/migrate-from-hockeykit-quincykit-to-hockeysdk-for-ios